# How to find and merge multi collection with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have e-commerce project with multi product type, i got some problem when querying product search.

the collection on my db like this:
- products_craft
- products_fashion
- products_travel
- products_food

Currently i try `.find()` each collection and merge it.

My existing code

```
const searchString = 'some product'

const final result = []

const resultOne = await ModelOne.find({ title: searchString })
const resultTwo = await ModelTow.find({ title: searchString })
const resultThree = await ModelThree.find({ title: searchString  })

result.push(resultOne)
result.push(resultTwo)
```

What the efficient, fast and best method for this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the fastest Mongo related way, make sure the field is indexed.

i would also use something like [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) to run all 3 searches simultaneously, that will save you alot of time.

it would look like this:

```
let Promise = require("bluebird");
const searchString = 'some product'

const final result = []
let results = Promise.all([ModelOne.find({ title: searchString }),
                           ModelTow.find({ title: searchString }),
                           ModelThree.find({ title: searchString })]);
return results.flat();
```

If you keep using your code `result.push(resultOne)` does not concat arrays but actually pushes the array as a whole, not sure you meant for this behavior.

Also note that if you do end up using bluebird you need to make sure your mongo/mongoose promises are a bluebird promise.
depending what you use you should read further on how to do it.

for mongoose i add `mongoose.Promise = Promise;` after the import.

Comment: thanks a lot for your helpfull answer. is efficient to implement live search using your method ?

Comment: Assuming this field is indexed this should run very fast. how fast? depending on scale and your machine obviously. if you do have runtime trouble i recommend re-thinking your data scheme as it shouldn't happen for this query.